# use orderby and group by together

Tags: mysql, sql

if I use order by and group by like this below

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM `entry` ORDER BY jc_epoc DESC)as b GROUP BY type
```

does this query **always** give me the biggest timeStamp in each type? 
if not , what is the right query?

Comment: can you add some sample data and schema?

Answer (score 1):

**No, It shouldn't** but apparently it does work more often than not. The real problem with your query is that theoritically it violates 1NF. Assuming that mysql always selects the first row in such a case, you design the query but actually it may differ and is not reliable as is suggested by the documentation. When selecting non-aggregated columns that are not always the same, **MySql is free to choose any value, so the resulting value that it actually shows is indeterminate.**

The question requires more clarity as to how many rows per type is required say for multiple max value instances per type are present. But I get a vague idea as to what you are trying - "You want to get the **max value for each type** and along with it all the other column values for **that row**"

To make a query that is determinate I would do -
If multiple rows per type is fine

```
SELECT *
FROM entry e1
WHERE (e1.type, e1.jc_epoc) IN
(    SELECT e.type, MAX(e.jc_epoc)
     FROM entry e
     GROUP BY e.type
)
```

If multiple rows per type is not fine, you'll have to use a key value to get single value

```
SELECT e2.* 
FROM entry e2 
LEFT OUTER JOIN entry e3 
ON e3.jc_epoc >= e2.jc_epoc
AND e3.type = e2.type
AND e3.id > e2.id
WHERE e3.id IS NULL
```

**Note :- Queries above may have more optimizations possible. For more clear/concise requirements queries may have optimized versions**
  Ex- for only MAX(jc_epoc) per type required and no other column values

```
SELECT e.type, MAX(e.jc_epoc)
FROM entry e
GROUP BY e.type
```

Feel free to [SQLFiddle it](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c9c2/10).